# Issue while printing flow document: "the calling thread cannot access this object as a differnt thread owns it"

Tags: wpf, multithreading, printing, backgroundworker

The code below keeps giving me the following error: **The calling thread cannot access this object as a differnt thread owns it**

I tried using:

- SynchronizationContext
- Application.Current.Dispatcher
- Windows.Threading.Dispatcher

---

```
private void PrintDocument()
    {
        PrintQueue printQueue = null;
        using (var worker = new BackgroundWorker())
        {
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            try
            {
                worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
                {
                    string actualServerHostName = "\\\\" + Dns.GetHostEntry(Config.Default.printer.printServer.TrimStart('\\')).HostName;
                    var printServer = new PrintServer(actualServerHostName);
                    printQueue = printServer.GetPrintQueue(Config.Default.printer.defaultPrinterName);
                    printQueue.UserPrintTicket = printDlg.PrintTicket;
                    e.Result = printQueue;
                };
                worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        printQueue = e.Result as PrintQueue;
                        var flowDocument = CreateFlowDocument();
                        PrintFlowDocument(printQueue, flowDocument.DocumentPaginator);
                    }, DispatcherPriority.Send);

                    InProgress = false;
                };
                InProgress = true;
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                worker.CancelAsync();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

private XpsDocumentWriter GetPrintXpsDocumentWriter(PrintQueue printQueue)
    {
        XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);
        return xpsWriter;
    }

    public void PrintFlowDocument(PrintQueue printQueue, DocumentPaginator document)
    {
        XpsDocumentWriter xpsDocumentWriter = GetPrintXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);
        PrintDocumentPaginator(xpsDocumentWriter, document);
    }

    private void PrintDocumentPaginator(XpsDocumentWriter xpsDocumentWriter, DocumentPaginator document)
    {
        try
        {
            xpsDocumentWriter.WriteAsync(document);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _dialogService.ShowErrorAsync("Error occured: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private IDocumentPaginatorSource CreateFlowDocument()
    {
        FlowDocument doc = (FlowDocument)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(@"/[assembly];component/Controls/PrintTicketControl.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        doc.DataContext = this;
        return doc;
    }
```

It fails when calling **xpsDocumentWriter.WriteAsync(document);** in the **PrintDocumentPaginator** method.
Having a look at the stack trace it seems like the PrintQueue is blowing up. 
I also checked the threads on which the controls are created and that I am successfully back on the Main thread when calling the PrintDocument function.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Well, `WriteAsync` clearly suggests the creation of a background thread or the like.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same issue even if I use the standard synchronous method **Write(document)** instead of WriteAsync().

Comment: Try it without the backgroundworker. You don't need to Invoke in a Completed event, and the DoWork doesn't seem correct either.

Comment: Hey Henk. The reason I need to background worker is that getting the print server takes awful amount of time. All works without the background process, but then the UI hangs for almost a minute or more sometimes while getting the print server. So, I figured I could possibly do that on the background thread, and marshall the results back onto the main thread. Which also works, but then it blows up while printing...

Comment: The isolate just that part  with `Task.Run()`. Keep it simple.

Comment: And of course, create an async/await path all the way doen from the toplevel event handler.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?